# Is ordering a Django Queryset faster than a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have converted my queryset into a dataframe in the application using `django-pandas`:

```
from django_pandas.io import read_frame

qs = Entry.objects.filter(
    date__range=(start_date, end_date),
).select_related(
    'user', 'project'
)

df = read_frame(
    qs,
    fieldnames=[
        'id', 'date', 'user', 'user__id', 'project__name', 
        'project_id'
    ]
)
```

I was deciding whether to add an `order_by` to the query or to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) the dataframe with pandas. They will both have the same functionality so the choice is down to speed.

There are 64k records in the table I am querying.

Comment: What's the question? Did you test?

Comment: My feeling is sorting the queryset will be faster because that's done at a database-level.

Comment: Database should be faster. I usually find pandas to be awfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

After testing with timeit I got:

```
db ordering is: 0.09235725016333163
df ordering is: 17.110706679988652
```